# How to hide Microsoft Rewards in Edge browser

Tags: microsoft-edge, windows-11

I have a PC with Windows 11 and the Edge browser. I want to get rid of the "Rewards" on the new tab page.

If you search the internet for "microsoft edge disable rewards" you get multiple websites explaining to you how to use the settings of the browser (duh!).
But this setting does not work for me: The rewards badge is still showing in the "new tab" page (top right next to the settings-cog):
[image: Rewards badge still showing on new tab page but setting disabled]
My PC was upgraded from Windows 10. On a different PC (new Laptop) it works as expected (disabeling the setting hides the rewards badge). Maybe this is is the source for the error?

**I have tried the following on my PC (to no avail)**:

- Enabling the setting, restarting edge and disabling it again.
- Deleting `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge` and starting Edge (this leads to Edge starting the "New install" greetings etc. but does not help the rewards badge: the setting is still not effective)
- Searched the internet for group policies concerning Edge + Microsoft Rewards (there is `Edge (Chromium): Show Microsoft Rewards experiences`, but it doesn't seem to exist any more [for my machine])
- Searched the internet for regedit keys, added and disabled them (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge`->`ShowMicrosoftRewards`: `0`)
- Searched `Edge://flags` for "reward": no entries

Is this a known bug of Windows/Edge? Are there any other ways to disable Microsoft Rewards for Edge?

Comment: Is your Microsoft Account actually an Azure AD account? Windows 11 Home or Professional?

Comment: Since Edge has advertising "baked in", you might consider other browsers.

Comment: I agree with @DrMoishePippik. Edge was a good enough substitute until they started adding bulk. Switch to Chrome, Vivaldi, Firefox or something else.

Comment: Chrome by default will link to your Google Account. Firefox has whatever their synchronization account is called.  The rewards balance can be hidden.  However, if you are unhappy with the connection to your Microsoft Account, the simplest way is just don't synchronize your profile to a MS account.  This will efficiently hide the balance.

Comment: If you hover the cursor over this entry, do you see a 3-points icon? Click it to see a menu where you may suppress the entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error the only thing that helped was resetting the entire Edge installation: uninstalling via cmd and reinstalling (I don't remember the exact steps; I followed various instructions I found via google).

In the end I followed one of the commentors' advice: I ditched Edge because it got bloated.

Answer (score 1):

- Click the three dots ... top right and select 'settings'
- Under 'Your profile' select 'Microsoft Rewards'
- Disable the button to earn 'Microsoft Rewards'
- Restart Edge

[image: No rewards icon top right]

Comment: That's exactly what is shown in the screenshot in the question itself and did not work.

Comment: I didn't look carefully enough at your question I am sorry.   The above procedure did work for me on a new build of Windows 10 yesterday.   Maybe MS have fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I chose to opt-out of the Microsoft Rewards program and it disappeared from the Profile selector etc.
Just be aware that you'll lose any accumulated points.

Visit:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-opt-out-of-microsoft-rewards-ff4eb882-ad54-aa47-1f84-dc9c45a0bd20

Which in turn leads to:
https://rewards.microsoft.com/optout