# How to get rid of Microsoft Rewards notifications?

Tags: windows, windows-11, microsoft-account

[image: Microsoft Rewards Annoying Notification]

My Windows 11 PC randomly pops up a notification about Microsoft Rewards.  How do I get rid of this?

- I'm not logged in with a Microsoft account
- I don't use Edge
- "Get tips and suggestions when using Windows" is disabled
- "Suggest ways to get the most out of Windows and finish setting up this device" is disabled
- Windows welcome experience is disabled

I'm not sure where it's coming from, but I'd like to nuke the whole "feature".  Any ideas?

Comment: It is nothing to worry about. Dismiss it (0.1%)  That is what I do. You probably use Office (even though no Microsoft Account.

Comment: @John - This notification is not generated by Office.

Comment: It shows as a reward from my Office setup.  Maybe different for me.

Comment: While you might not personally use Microsoft Edge, I suspect a profile has still be created, with "Show rewards points in Microsoft Edge user profile" turned on.  To verify this is the case, you would need to launch Microsoft Edge, and within Settings -> Profiles -> Microsoft Rewards you would need to disable it[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1703874/how-to-hide-microsoft-rewards-in-edge-browser).  If that still does not work, since you dont use Edge, try to Reset your Edge user profile. While it looks different, it could also be, a website notification but I doubt you use Bing.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound, it was checked on... turned it off now, and we'll see how it goes!

Comment: Great comment Ramhound, you should have posted that as an answer, probably would many people, and thanks, it helped me also.

Comment: The suggestion came with individuals, indicating it disabled Microsoft Rewards entirely, which I disagree with but makes me not confident it’s an actual fix

Comment: @Ramhound Unfortunately, this did not resolve the problem.  :-(